# Jasperstudio Report Book

Tags: jasper-reports, margins

I have several reports (which contain subreports) gathered in a Report Book. Reports and subreports have no margins, but I would like for all the pages in the report book to have them (of equal size). I tried to set it within the book (by clicking on the book --> properties --> left/right/top/bottom margin), but that does nothing - pages have no margins no matter what size I type in. Am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Report Book is actually composed of several elements, so you would actually have to go and set margins for those (or all) sections of the book that you want to see margins for.

Abstract_Book.jrxml, example created by choosing a report book in "Abstract Book" template design, actually contains instructions how are sections of the "book" organized, comparatively as are bands within a report element.

Hope this helps